# jQuery UI datepicker - month viewer

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I saw this feature in on a mootools plugins here: http://dev.base86.com/scripts/mootools_javascript_datepicker_calendar_eightysix.html

What happens is that when I click the month "January 2012", the calendar zooms out to show all the months, the left and right arrows navigate between years, and I can zoom into any month by clicking it.

How can this be done with jQuery UI datepicker?

Comment: The jQueryUI datepicker doesn't have that capability to my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

That is a mootools extension, it's not a core part of mootools framework.  I do like the basic idea, but like with their variation, you'd have to create a jQuery specific plugin (likely would be best to base it on the jQuery-ui widget framework) to perform this.

Alternatively, find a datepicker that already does this.